# How to install packages without documentation?

Tags: 12.04, apt, documentation

**Stage**

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to install some TexLive packages, but they requires their own documentation packages.

For example:

- `texlive-latex-extra` pulls `texlive-latex-extra-doc`.
- `texlive-pictures` pulls `texlive-pictures-doc`.
- etc.

Documentation packages are very very heavy, so avoid downloading them results in a faster installation.

**Question**

How can I install packages without documentation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In these cases, the -doc packages are not hard dependencies but recommendations. You can make apt not intall these by using:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install texlive-latex-extra
```

Comment: if I do it with ` --no-install-recommends` and without it shows same amount of megabytes to install in terminal. I though with the option it should show much less...

Comment: @MikeKlemin: Maybe you already had the docs installed before running the command?